# Interaction with the collection does not use the set accessor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
public class MainWindowVM : ViewModel
    {
        #region public members

        public User LocalUser
        {
            get => Settings.LocalUser;
            set
            {
                Settings.LocalUser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public WebUser SelectedUser
        {
            get => selectedUser;
            set
            {
                selectedUser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string InputMessage
        {
            get => inputMessage;
            set
            {
                inputMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public List<Message> MessageList
        {
            get
            {
                if (selectedUser == null)
                    return null;
                return SelectedUser.MessageThread;
            }
            set
            {
                SelectedUser.MessageThread = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public RelayCommand SendMessageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return sendMessageCommand ??
                    (sendMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        SendMessage();
                    }));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region public methods

        public MainWindowVM(Window window)
        {
            Window MainWindow = window;
            MawLib.WindowResizer windowResizer = new MawLib.WindowResizer(window);
            Settings.InitializeInstance();
            SelUser = SelectUser;
            UserListRaw = new List<WebUser>
            {
                new WebUser(new UserId("SomeTestUser23")),
                new WebUser(new UserId("NoName"))
            };
            WebClient.Connect();
        }
        public void SelectUser(WebUser user)
        {
            SelectedUser = user;
            MessageList = SelectedUser.MessageThread;
        }

        #endregion

        #region private members

        private WebUser selectedUser;
        private string inputMessage;

        #endregion

        #region private methods

        private void SendMessage()
        {
            if (InputMessage != "" && InputMessage != null)
            {
                MessageList.Add(new Message(InputMessage, LocalUser, SelectedUser));
                WebClient.SendRequest(new Message(InputMessage, Settings.LocalUser, selectedUser), Request.RequestType.Message);
                InputMessage = "";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Need to have a Message List.Add interacted via the Message List property, but for some reason it bypasses it. I also tried to access the accessor via assignment, but this also bypassed the property. I was looking for information about this, but I didn't find anything suitable, maybe I was looking badly?

Comment: **adding** something to a list surely does not **set** that list. The setter would be called if you´d assign a new list to that property.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dzianis Karpuk, need to use ObservableCollection instead of List, everything works as it should.